# Summation of JSON values in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have a set of JSON data stored in an array. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "key": "2"
}
```

and I'm trying to sum all of the "key" values inside the array of JSON strings with a for/in loop.

```
var total = 0;
    for (var object in array) {
    total += object.value;
}
```

The expected output is 3. However, this arrangement seems incorrect. I'm working in Node.js. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean summation of json values? Are you trying to add string values?

Comment: Try `of` instead of `in`: `for (var object of array)`

Comment: you want to add one and two?? pls b more specific

Comment: you are talking about an object. [JSON](http://json.org/) is a string.

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. I will edit the post to be more specific and accurate.

Comment: maybe you add the wanted result as well.

Comment: Are you asking for a program that understands [English counting words](http://www.marijn.org/everything-is-4/counting-0-to-100/english/)?

Comment: No, the JSON holds numeric values 1, 2, etc. I've fixed this in the original post. I've added the expected result as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have an array looking like this:

```
var array = [{id: "one", key: 2}, {id: "two", key: 8}]
```

You can simply get the total like that:

```
var total = array.reduce((x,y) => x + y.key, 0)
```

However, if you have a JSON string, where the values are also strings (like `[{"id":"one","key":"2"},{"id":"two","key":"8"}]'`), then you need to parse the JSON first and parse the values as numbers:

```
JSON.parse(array).reduce((x,y) => x + Number.parseFloat(y.key), 0)
```

Comment: Just saw the original post was edited... The object structure has changed, no more value property, but key instead?

Comment: My bad. I realized the key/value pair in the example probably shouldn't have "key" named "value".

Comment: All good, I changed it. Hope this helps, if not, please provide the full array and we'll work it out.

Comment: This works for me! Out of curiosity, is there a way to do this with the for/in loop, or is reduce() necessary?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not an array of objects, but one object with several properties.

You can use `Object.keys()` to get the properties as an array, then `map` to retrieve the values for each of those properties, and finally `reduce` on that array to calculate the sum:

```js
const obj = {
 "id": "1",
 "key": "2"
}

const total = Object.keys(obj) // Get keys
    .map( key => +obj[key] ) // Get values as numbers
    .reduce ( (a,b) => a+b ); // sum up

console.log(total);
```